# Database Structure/Planning Queries

Tags: mysql, execution-plan

I'm looking for any guidance possible and not necessarily asking for "the solution" as such. In a MySQL database, I want to understand how to do a capacity analysis for a company. Such that a Company needs to make:

- 20,000 of Product 1 per year
- 20,000 of Product 2 per year
- 20,000 of Product 3 per year

---

- Machine 1 can make 10,000 a year
- Machine 2 can make 10,000 a year
- Machine 3 can make 10,000 a year
- Machine 4 can make 10,000 a year
- Machine 5 can make 10,000 a year
- Machine 6 can make 10,000 a year

---

- Product 1 can be made on Machine 1 and Machine 2 and Machine 3
- Product 2 can be made on Machine 2 and Machine 3 and Machine 4
- Product 3 can be made on Machine 4 and Machine 5 and Machine 6

I then need to do what-if analysis such that, if the demand for Product 1 goes up by 10,000 what impact does that have?

I then need to scale this up to thousands of products and more machines etc.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying you're trying to capacity plan to provision MySQL instance(s)?

Comment: Hi sorry - no i'm trying to understand how to do a capacity of this company. In the sense that how many products they can make etc. I've edited the question. Hopefully more clear. Thank you.

Comment: Ah ok. So you're basically trying to solve a capacity planning problem by coming up with an algorithm for allocating production most efficiently across the machines?

Comment: Yes exactly, on a high level annual basis. And I was hoping to be able to do as much as possible inside a mysql query.

Comment: This is doable, will try to write something up if I get a chance. I've done this in the past at a more granular level (having to consider shared components used to build the products) so this should be a simpler problem.

Comment: Thanks man. Would really appreciate any help! Hopefully speak soon! 

Comment: How many GB of data?  How many queries per second?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to design a schema that includes tables for machines, products, production capabilities, and a mapping of which machines can produce which products. Here's a basic outline:

Machines Table: Contains machine details (Machine ID, Capacity per year).
Products Table: Contains product details (Product ID, Annual Demand).
Machine_Product_Map Table: Maps which products can be made on which machines.

```
    CREATE TABLE Machines (
    MachineID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CapacityPerYear INT
    );
    
    CREATE TABLE Products (
    ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    AnnualDemand INT
    );

   CREATE TABLE Machine_Product_Map (
   MachineID INT,
   ProductID INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (MachineID) REFERENCES Machines(MachineID),
   FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES Products(ProductID)
   );
```

---insert the data with the table parameters above
-- Inserting Machines
INSERT INTO Machines VALUES (1, 10000), (2, 10000), ..., (6, 10000);

```
    -- Inserting Products
    INSERT INTO Products VALUES (1, 20000), (2, 20000), (3, 20000);

    -- Mapping Machines to Products
    INSERT INTO Machine_Product_Map VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), ...;
```

To analyze capacity, you'll write SQL queries to calculate the total production capacity available for each product based on machine mappings. Here's an example query to calculate the total capacity for a specific product:

```
    SELECT p.ProductID, SUM(m.CapacityPerYear) AS 
    TotalCapacity
    FROM Products p
    JOIN Machine_Product_Map mp ON p.ProductID = mp.ProductID
    JOIN Machines m ON mp.MachineID = m.MachineID
    WHERE p.ProductID = 1
    GROUP BY p.ProductID;
```

For the what-if analysis, you will adjust the demand in the Products table and rerun the analysis queries to see the impact. For example, if demand for Product 1 increases by 10,000 in your high volume example above.

```
    UPDATE Products SET AnnualDemand = AnnualDemand + 10000 WHERE ProductID = 1;
```